# How to call layout xml from another module

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin

I am setting ContentView in MainActivity as
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

I have other module in package as well, for that module I defined in gradle file `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` This once also has res/layout/activity_main.xml

So can I call activity_main.xml from another module from MainActivity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can, but your module must have another Android packageId (EDIT: just to make sure, you declare your packageId inside your Android manifest).
So e.g. you have `com.example.app` for your app module and `com.example.lib` for your library. Then you can access your resource ids by `com.example.app.R` or `com.example.lib.R`.
So you would have `com.example.lib.R.layout.activity_main` for your layout inside your library module.

Comment: thnx, it works fine if I rename file. I am calling navigation drawer, so I can see drawer opening. e.g. `com.example.lib.R.layout.activity_main_drawer`  But if I just say `com.example.lib.R.layout.activity_main`   it still calls activity_main from app. Any reason?

Comment: Have you made sure your packageIds inside your two manifests are different? Or else you can't see the library ressources with the same name, if both are inside the same packageId and therefore both in different `com.example.lib.R` classes.

Comment: Yes I have added those in both. e.g.package="com.example.lib" It is only not working when it's same name

Comment: Yes it MUST happen, because in Java/Android you MUST have unique package names for classes with the same name or else the one that gets loaded first by the ClassLoader (in your case the `R` class inside the app module) HIDES the other one. Due to the generative nature of the `R`class, you have to have different packageIds for different Android modules, if you want to use the same names for your ressources.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is in Development Considerations section of http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

According to the resource, you cannot have 2 layouts called the same in different modules: one will override another even though your R files are correctly namespaced. It is very disappointing behaviour but it looks like the only way around it is prefixing.

Comment: You are right. If we use modules and usually one module will import other module, and Resource (R.java) will import first and namespace will be omitted. So DO NOT use the same layout name.

Answer (score 0):

aha, remember to leave CustomView as public. I lost few hours by missing it.